# how to return two values from a method?

Tags: c#

I have class were I have method. now I want send two calculated values out from the method same time. how i can do that, that I can call method from main program? my program returns only first value now. Can i return somehow something like this: console.writeLine("first value" + x + "second value is:" + y?
my method code:

```
public static double calculate(double r)
{             
    double x;
    double y;
    x = r * r;
    y = r * r * r;

    return x; // should i put something here or shuld i do somehow array?
}
```

Comment: You can use `Tuple` or create a custom class to hold the values you want to output.

Comment: The proper term to use when referring to returning data from method is "return". Probably because of that you could not find any similar answers -  use followng search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20return%20multiple%20values%20from%20method if duplicate is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

use out parameters

```
double in1, in2;
double result = calculate(10, out in1, out in2);


public static double calculate(double r, out double x, out double y)
{
    x = r * r;
    y = r * r * r;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to make them both out parameters you might as well make the method return void.